# Search and output item if found in more than 90% of files

Tags: bash, shell

I have 100 txt files, each text file contain IDs in only one long column. I want to find each ID in all 100 files, if an ID appears in at least 90 out of the 100 files, the ID will be appended to a file. the program will look for each ID in all files and output all IDs found in at least 90% of the files. I have an idea of what to do but I couldnt put it together in a shell script. for example, each file looks like this

```
file_1.txt

BGIBMGA010657
BGIBMGA010658
BGIBMGA010659
BGIBMGA010664
BGIBMGA010666
BGIBMGA010671
BGIBMGA010673
BGIBMGA010674
BGIBMGA010676
BGIBMGA010685
BGIBMGA010687
BGIBMGA010699
BGIBMGA010714
BGIBMGA010723
```

The code will do something like this

```
for line in file
   for files in *.txt
      if line found in at least 90 files
         append line in a new file
```

I need to translate it into a shell script.
thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific issue ?

Comment: I would use [tag:awk] for this: keep a count of all ids found, and after all the files have been processed, loop over all the ids and if the count >= 90 then print it.

Comment: That is exactly what i want to do, but I couldnt come up with a shell script in that regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { num_files = ARGC - 1 }
    { count[$1]++ }
    END {
        for (id in count)
            if ( (count[id]/num_files) >= 0.9)
                print id
    }
' *.txt
```